# How can I redirect string to stdin in ruby

Tags: ruby, stdin

I need to do something like this.

```
10.times do |i|
    file = File.open("./data/#{i+1}.in")
    $stdin = file.read
    load 'sum.rb'
    file.close
end
```

And this is sum.rb

```
gets.chomp.split().map { |e| e.to_i }
puts array.inject(:+)
```

Is there any way to work this out?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to implement the grading system which will test the program by giving them inputs and check the outputs if it is matched or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stdin` and the result of `File.open` are both [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html) objects, so rather than assign the results of `file.read` to `$stdin`, assign `file` itself.

```
10.times do |i|
    file = File.open("./data/#{i+1}.in")
    $stdin = file
    load 'sum.rb'
    file.close
end
```

This will fix your immediate problem, your `sum.rb` won’t work as it is (`array` isn’t defined anywhere).

In a more robust version of this you would probably want to retain the original value of `$stdin` and reset it after you are finished.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way but if you don't mind to spawn sum.rb as a new process (which would simulate a test better imho) you could do it like this:

```
require "open3"

10.times do |i|
  File.open("./data/#{i+1}.in") do |file|
    Open3.popen2e("ruby sum.rb") do |stdin, stdout, wait_thr|
      stdin.puts(file.read)
      exit_status = wait_thr.value # Process::Status object returned.
    end
  end
end
```

Doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e